# Can't add data to the table postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm trying to save to a table the data taken from the elements on the form when the button is pressed. I have already rewritten the "query" method many times, but always the same error. Thank you.
[I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XgTm.png)

I thought that the problem might be in the data types, played around with that but nothing helped me either.

```
 private void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                string Name = txtName.Text;
                int Age = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtAge.Text);
                string Sex = txtSex.Text;
                int Phone = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtPhone.Text);
                string Type = cmbType.SelectedItem.ToString();
                conn.Open();
                string query = $"INSERT INTO public.customers (name,age,sex,phone,group) VALUES('{Name}','{Age}','{Sex}','{Phone}','{Type}')";

                NpgsqlCommand nCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
                nCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Select();
                MessageBox.Show("Продукт Додано Успішно.", "Додання клієнта", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Помилка: " + ex.Message, "Помилка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Connect to DB:

```
        private string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};" +
            "User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
            "localhost", 5432, "postgres",
            "123", "fitnessСlub");

        private NpgsqlConnection conn;
        private string sql;
        private NpgsqlCommand cmd;
        private DataTable dt;
        private int rowIndex = -1;
```

Insertion in DataGridView:

```
        private void Select()
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY Custid ASC";
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                conn.Close();
                DGV1.DataSource = null;
                DGV1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Помилка: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

[The table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxcqo.png)

Comment: "group" is reserved word. Use a better name, of use double quotes " around it: "group". And something else, are you sure this code is save against SQL injection?

Comment: It worked, you are very attentive. I am very grateful to you, have a nice day. Security in the project is not taken into account as it is educational.

Comment: Why teach yourself bad practices?

Comment: You are absolutely right, later I will look for an article about this and read it. As they say, do it right, it will be okay. Thank you.